# How can I get/set a property dynamically having a path without recursion?

Tags: php

I would like to get/set a property of a property of a property (...) having the path. For example, if I have

```
$obj->a->b->c
```

I would like to get it with

```
get_property(["a", "b", "c"], $obj)
```

I've written this function for getting it and it works for array and object values but I need it for objects.

```
public static function get_value_by_path($index, $array) {

    if (!$index || empty($index)) 
        return NULL;

    if (is_array($index)) {
        if (count($index) > 1) {
            if (is_array($array) && array_key_exists($index[0], $array)) {
                return static::get_value_by_path(array_slice($index, 1), $array[$index[0]]);
            }
            if (is_object($array)) {
                return static::get_value_by_path(array_slice($index, 1), $array->{$index[0]});
            }
            return NULL;
        }
        $index = $index[0];
    }

    if (is_array($array) && array_key_exists($index, $array)) 
        return $array[$index];

    if (is_object($array) && property_exists($array, $index)) return $array->$index;
        return NULL;
}
```

My question is: **is it possible to do this without recursion?**

I haven't found similiar questions.

Comment: If you can do it for arrays, then where is the problem doing it for objects?

Comment: Nothing. I've already done it. My question is: can I do it without recursion?

Comment: Can you make your question consistent? You ask about a setting properties and show us the code of a method that gets properties. Can you choose one? I think you want the alternative of the code you show. Is that right?

Comment: You can do it in a standard loop, if you use a reference to point to the current position on your “path”.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I've asked for both but they're very similiar so that's all the same

Comment: @CBroe It can be a good solution. Maybe is there a standard PHP function for doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function below will do it:

```
function get_property($propertyPath, $object)
{
  foreach ($propertyPath as $propertyName) {
    // basic protection against bad path 
    if (!property_exists($object,$property)) return NULL;
    // get the property 
    $property = $object->{$propertyName};
    // if it is not an object it has to be the end point
    if (!is_object($property)) return $property;
    // if it is an object replace current object 
    $object = $property;
  }
  return $object;
}
```

depending on what you exactly want to can build in some error code. You can use the get function if you want to set something like this:

```
function set_property($propertyPath, &$object, $value)
{
  // pop off the last property
  $lastProperty = array_pop($propertyPath);
  // get the object to which the last property should belong
  $targetObject = get_property($propertyPath,$object);
  // and set it to value if it is valid
  if (is_object($targetObject) && property_exists($targetObject,$lastProperty)) {
    $targetObject->{$lastProperty} = $value;
  }
}
```

I do however like recursion, and with it these functions could possibly be better.

Comment: @TheDeveloper: Yes, sorry, didn't check the code carefully enough. Changed the `$object` in `set_property()` because of the ampersand.

Comment: Made a further simplification.