# PHP referenced parameters not modified in array

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get &$object changed in array stuff. I feel PHP seems to work in a strange way.

```php
    private function set_property($propertyPath, &$object, $value)
    {
        $targetObject = &$object;

        if (is_object($targetObject) && property_exists($targetObject, $lastProperty)) {

            // &$object is successfully modified

            $targetObject->{"aaa"} = $value;
        } else if (isset($targetObject) && is_array($targetObject)) {

            // &$object fails in being modified

            $targetObject["aaa"] = $value;
        }
    }
```

I am doing this one, but the thing is that I want to walk through an object and array mixed stuff.

[How can I get/set a property dynamically having a path without recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275454/how-can-i-get-set-a-property-dynamically-having-a-path-without-recursion)

Comment: Where does `$lastProperty` come from?

Comment: I have corrected it but it is not related to the issue.

Comment: Does your object extends `ArrayObject`? How does it _fails_? Error or just not modified? You can't simply access object with `[]` notation, it's not JS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP object like array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007695/php-object-like-array)

Comment: The code you've shared [works for me](https://3v4l.org/U1qlv). Whatever the issue is, it must be somewhere else.

Comment: Nothing works.. I finally chose to use json_decode(json_encode($object), FALSE).. I worried if this costs a lot.

Comment: Serialising and unserialising should definitively break any link between variables. The code you've shared doesn't exhibit the problem you're asking about. If your actual question is how to create randomly nested array hierarchies without recursion I think you should ask directly.